# How to reduce the distance between yAxes in Chart.js?

Tags: vue.js, charts, chart.js, nuxt.js

This is my data and configuration :

```js
{
  chartData: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple'],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: '',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 167, 88, 0.6)',
        borderColor: '#007a58',
        borderWidth: '2',
        lineTension: 0,
        pointStyle: 'line',
        data: [12, 15, 22, 32, 44],
      },
    ],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          position: 'right',
          ticks: {
            suggestedMax: 45,
            suggestedMin: 0,
            stepSize: 5,
          },
        },
        {
          position: 'left',
          ticks: {
            suggestedMax: 45,
            suggestedMin: 0,
            stepSize: 5,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
}
```

I've managed to create 2 yAxes with 1 dataset. But the yAxes distance is too wide. If without yAxes configuration the distance is normal.

This is the screenshot with yAxes configuration :

[image: With yAxes configuration]

This is the screenshot without yAxes configuration :

[image: without yAxes configuration]

Comment: The first yAxis on the right is starting at 0. This is the only issue I guess. Also, please **do not** delete this post when the issue is solved.. No point at all. Also, try to highlight your code please.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you set `suggestedMin` of the `position: 'right'` of your `yAxes` object to be

```
suggestedMin: Math.min.apply(null, this.chartData.datasets[0].data)
```

This should set the minimum of the right axis to be on the minimal value of your dataset rather than starting from `0`.

Not sure if it should auto-find it by itself because it is "suggested". There is maybe a better way but this one should at least work.

---

Reference for the minimum code was found here: https://medium.com/coding-at-dawn/the-fastest-way-to-find-minimum-and-maximum-values-in-an-array-in-javascript-2511115f8621